# Trouble displaying nth element of an array through function

Tags: arrays, bash, function, return, space

I'm looking for retrieving the nth element from an array which contains spaces.
Let's take for example:

```
ARRAY=("This is" "a test" "array")
```

I've created the following function:

```
ReturnElementFromId() {
    local result="${@[$1]}"
    echo result
}

echo `ReturnElementFromId 0 "${ARRAY[@]}"`
```

The function may appear useless, but I need it to work like so.
It was designed to return the $1th index of the given array.

I made some research on Internet and didn't found any answers.
I know that the code I wrote (especially `result="${@[$1]}"`) is false because

> **Victor Zamanian:** @ (and *) are "Special Parameters" and because they are not valid
>   array names, ${@} does refer to the numbered parameters

Unfortunately `result="${$1}` doesn't work and tried almost all combinaisons I could think of >.<"
Does someone have any clues ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your code. You need to have in mind that actually all the parameters you send to your function are an array of values.

```
#!/bin/bash


ARRAY=("This is" "a test" "array")

function ReturnElementFromId() {
    local ix="$1" && shift
    local arr=("$@")

    echo "${arr[$ix]}"
}

echo `ReturnElementFromId 0 "${ARRAY[@]}"`
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Impressive how fast you unlocked me! That works perfectly, I'll analyze that in order to prevent future mistakes. Thanks !

Comment: This is better, but fix a few things 1) drop the `function` keyword 2) no need for `&& shift`, run it no matter what `; shift` 3) Don't recommend backticks and instead recommend `$(..)`

Comment: I don't understand the use of the echo at all - the function handles that. Just call it as `ReturnElementFromId 0 "${ARRAY[@]}"` without embedding it. But maybe it's just representative of a need, in which case - use `$(...)` rather than backticks.